# AWS Amplify - build.yml file for Java and gradle as part of backend

Tags: yaml, aws-amplify

I have an amplify app which has both frontend and backend components.

I added the storage and api (REST with Java) to the backend. I installed jdk11 and gradle locally and everything works fine. I even did `amplify push` and it went successfully, although this needs to go through CI/CD

I have CI/CD enabled for this app and both the frontend and backend changes will be picked from the git repo branch, and then built and deployed. My front end is fine, however I couldn't add the entries correctly for corritto 11 and gradle 6 in backend part of `build.yml` and build is failing

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - wget https://corretto.aws/downloads/latest/amazon-corretto-11-aarch64-linux-jdk.tar.gz -P /tmp
        - tar xvf /tmp/amazon-corretto-*.tar.gz --directory /usr/bin
        - echo export PATH="/usr/bin/amazon-corretto-11.0.20.8.1-linux-aarch64/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
        - echo export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/amazon-corretto-11.0.20.8.1-linux-aarch64/bin/java" >> ~/.bashrc
        - source ~/.bashrc
        - java -version
        - wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip -P /tmp
        - unzip -d /usr/bin /tmp/gradle-*.zip
        - export PATH="/usr/bin/gradle-6.3/bin:$PATH"
        - gradle --version
        - amplifyPush --simple
```

This is the build error

```
# Executing command: echo export PATH="/usr/bin/amazon-corretto-11.0.20.8.1-linux-aarch64/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
2023-08-16T06:20:06.897Z [INFO]: # Executing command: echo export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/amazon-corretto-11.0.20.8.1-linux-aarch64/bin/java" >> ~/.bashrc
2023-08-16T06:20:06.898Z [INFO]: # Executing command: source ~/.bashrc
2023-08-16T06:20:07.335Z [INFO]: # Executing command: java -version
2023-08-16T06:20:07.336Z [WARNING]: /codebuild/output/src1547455551/src/ballot-betting/amplify.sh: line 21: /usr/bin/amazon-corretto-11.0.20.8.1-linux-aarch64/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
2023-08-16T06:20:07.337Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-08-16T06:20:07.338Z [INFO]: Please check the supported SSR features to find if your build failure is related to an unsupported feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-Amplify-support.html#supported-unsupported-features. You may also find this troubleshooting guide useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html
```

The very first error before I added the backend section

```
Initialized provider successfully.
2023-08-16T04:43:41.140Z [INFO]: [31mUnable to find Java version >=11 on the path. Download link: https://amzn.to/2UUljp9[39m
                                 [31mUnable to find Java compiler version >=11 on the path. Download link: https://amzn.to/2UUljp9[39m
                                 [31mUnable to find Gradle version >=5 on the path. Download link: *Removed Bitly*[39m
2023-08-16T04:43:41.140Z [WARNING]: ✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
2023-08-16T04:43:41.141Z [INFO]:  Missing required dependencies to package electionsLambda
                                 Learn more at: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/troubleshooting/
```

Can some one please help on how to add java11, gradle 5 to the backend part of yml correctly?

I think it would be better if we have a way to auto generate this yml file.